# Zend Framework 2 Navigation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Why vew helper duplicates the menu displays, though I give him a different set of data. Twice menu 'navigation1' is displayed

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation1')->menu() ?>
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation2')->menu() ?>
```

But the following code, individually, displays a different menu

```
<?php //echo $this->navigation('navigation1')->menu() ?>
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation2')->menu() ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation1')->menu() ?>
<?php //echo $this->navigation('navigation2')->menu() ?>
```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the factories and config arrays you are using to assemble the navigation? What you are showing should work fine so the issue lies in one of the other files but I would have to see them to help you.